# how type checking fails?

Tags: lambda-calculus, type-theory, type-checking, types-and-programming-languages, polymorphisms

I was doing a type checking example in system f sub on paper to understand how it works.

according to Pierce's book [Types and Programming Languages](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/), numbers and their types are following in system f sub. (see chapter 26.3, page 399)

```
   1)top is universal type, 
   2)capital letters are type variables, small letters are term variables  

    church number 1
    sone = λA<:top.λB<:A.λC<:A.λx:(A-->B).λy:C.x y
    stwo = λA<:top.λB<:A.λC<:A.λx:(A-->B).λy:C.x (x y)

    type for church number 0
    SZero = ∀A<:top.∀B<:A.∀C<:A.(A-->B)-->C-->C

    type for numbers except 0
    SPos = ∀A<:top.∀B<:A.∀C<:A.(A-->B)-->C-->B
    SNat = ∀A<:top.∀B<:A.∀C<:A.(A-->B)-->C-->A
```

for the type checking

```
   Γ |-  stwo :  SZero
```

should fail.

book said "SPos is inhabited by all the elements of SNat except SZero".
 Also I saw there is a input test [test files](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~plclub/poplmark/), it shows above example should fail.

Therefore, I assume

```
 Γ |-  sone :  SZero
```

should fail too.

I want to see how it is going to fail and did pen-paper type checking as following (see type checking rules in the same book, previous page)

```
  1)for convenience, I wrote from top to down fashion
  2)variables are given distinct

   Γ |-  (λA<:top.λB<:A.λC<:A.λx:(A-->B).λy:C.x y)  
       : (∀A1<:top.∀B1<:A1.∀C1<:A1.(A1-->B1)-->C1-->C1)
   ---------------------------------------------(T-TABS) =>assume A=A1,top=top
                                                             ,and renamed A1 to A 
  A<:top |- (λB<:A.λC<:A.λx:(A-->B).λy:C.x y) 
           :(∀B1<:A.∀C1<:A.(A-->B1)-->C1-->C1) 
  ----------------------------------------------(T-TABS) =>assume B=B1, rename B1 to B

A<:top,B<:A |- (λC<:A.λx:(A-->B).λy:C.x y)
              :(∀C1<:A.(A-->B)-->C1-->C1)
 ---------------------------------------------------(T-TABS) =>assume C=C1, rename C1 to C
 A<:top,B<:A,C<:A |- (λx:(A-->B).λy:C.x y)
                   : (A-->B)-->C-->C
 -----------------------------------------------------T_ABS =>have A-->B=A-->B,   get A=A,B=B,remove them

 A<:top,B<:A,C<:A,x:A-->B |- (λy:C.x y) : C-->C 
 ------------------------------------------------T-ABS ==>have  C=C
 A<:top,B<:A,C<:A,x:A-->B,y:C | ( x y ) : C         
 ----------------------------------------------- T-APP  introduce type variable T1
 A<:top,B<:A,C<:A,x:A-->B,y:C | x : T1-->C  A:top,B<:A,C<:A,x:A-->B,y:C | y:T1     
 ----------------------------------------  ----------------------------------
   have X:T1-->C                                   have y:T1
        X:A-->B                                         y:C
    so, T1=/=A, B=/=C                                   T1=/=C
```

so fails I assume.

I thought the type checking

```
  Γ |-  sone :  SPos
```

should be successful, but it ..

```
 1) type is different a bit here

   Γ |-  (λA<:top.λB<:A.λC<:A.λx:(A-->B).λy:C.x y)  
       : (∀A1<:top.∀B1<:A1.∀C1<:A1.(A1-->B1)-->C1-->B1)


        intermediate steps are all same 
         .................
               .....
  A<:top,B<:A,C<:A,x:A-->B |- (λy:C.x y) : C-->B 
 ------------------------------------------------T-ABS ==>have  C=C
 A<:top,B<:A,C<:A,x:A-->B,y:C | ( x y ) : B         
 ----------------------------------------------- T-APP  introduce type variable T1
 A<:top,B<:A,C<:A,x:A-->B,y:C | x : T1-->B  A:top,B<:A,C<:A,x:A-->B,y:C | y:T1     
 ----------------------------------------  ----------------------------------
   have X:T1-->B                                   have y:T1
        X:A-->B                                         y:C
    so, T1=/=A, B=B                                   T1=/=C
```

See, these two type checking ended up pretty same, I did not understand why the first type checking should fail, while second one should be successful.

How to do type checking in system F sub?
If you know, please correct me, thank you.

Comment: [Cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39769680/how-type-checking-works-in-system-f-sub)?

Comment: @AntonTrunov. not sure where it will get attention. I delete one of them once another is answered.

Comment: I think this is the right place. A tip: you can use MathJax to typeset formulas on this site.

Comment: Cross-posted on CS.SE and SO: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/64075/755, http://stackoverflow.com/q/39769680/781723. Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: @D.W. another one is deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out. The key is using sub-typing rules.

```
         ctx[]|- t:S     ctx[]|S<:T
         ---------------------------t-sub
               ctx[]|-t:T
```

By applying this rule after T-APP rules, you can eliminate all "A==B" equations by using

```
       eq(A,A) -> .
       eq(A-->B,A-->B) -> eq(A,A),eq(B,B).
         ........
```

One can easily observe how to write these rules to eliminate "eq"s. If there is one or some "eq"s left, such as "eq(A,B)", means a contradiction, so type checking fails.

If you can eliminate all "eq"s, means type checking successful.

One important point about "t-sub" rule is that it is not suitable for implementation, because it is not syntax directed. That rule is applicable for any statement with the form of

```
       ctx[]|t:T
```

therefore, algorithmic version is proved to has the same power in the book "Types and Programming Languages".

:)